# Can I program to avoid GPU memory errors? like cuMemAlloc results in CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management, cuda, anaconda

I am doing some fun testing of my GPU Nvidia video card.   Set up a nice program that does operations on the intel CPU and then does them by vectorizing them on the GPU.   It is cool, because I get about an 80x speed improvement when I use the GPU.   However, with some simple programs, I have been able to just blow out the memory constraint and one of my programs, trashes the kernal.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize
import gc
@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='cuda')
def loopGPU(vStart, vEnd):
    vPosition=vStart
    vOriginal=vStart
    for vStart in range(vEnd):
        vPosition=vPosition+1
    print('Counted from: ', vOriginal, ' to: ', vEnd, ' by: 1 ' )
    return(vPosition)
def loop2aTrillion(vStart, vEnd):
    start = timer()
    vNewStart=loopGPU(vStart, vEnd)
    duration = timer() - start
    print('GPU Loop Time',duration)
```

> > > loop2aTrillion(1,100000000)
> > >       Counted from:  1.000000  to:  100000000.000000  by: 1
> > >       GPU Loop Time 3.7991681657728336

So it works great to about 100 million..   But If I go to a Billion or even 500 million..  I get this amazing error from CUDA

See my try to see where the breaking point is..

> > > loop2aTrillion(1,100)
> > >       Counted from:  1.000000  to:  100.000000  by: 1
> > >       GPU Loop Time 0.10281342493556167
> > >       loop2aTrillion(1,1000000)
> > >       Counted from:  1.000000  to:  1000000.000000  by: 1
> > >       GPU Loop Time 0.048263507262902294
> > >       loop2aTrillion(1,100000000)
> > >       Counted from:  1.000000  to:  100000000.000000  by: 1
> > >       GPU Loop Time 3.7804056272377693
> > >       loop2aTrillion(1,100000000)
> > >       Counted from:  1.000000  to:  100000000.000000  by: 1
> > >       GPU Loop Time 3.797257584627573
> > >       loop2aTrillion(1,1000000000)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "", line 3, in loop2aTrillion
> > >         File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\dispatcher.py", line 88, in **call**
> > >           return CUDAUFuncMechanism.call(self.functions, args, kws)
> > >         File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\npyufunc\deviceufunc.py", line 311, in call
> > >           return devout.copy_to_host().reshape(outshape)
> > >         File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 212, in _require_cuda_context
> > >           return fn(*args, **kws)
> > >         File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 252, in copy_to_host
> > >           _driver.device_to_host(hostary, self, self.alloc_size, stream=stream)
> > >         File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 1776, in device_to_host
> > >           fn(host_pointer(dst), device_pointer(src), size, *varargs)
> > >         File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 288, in safe_cuda_api_call
> > >           self._check_error(fname, retcode)
> > >         File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 323, in _check_error
> > >           raise CudaAPIError(retcode, msg)
> > >       numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: [719] Call to cuMemcpyDtoH results in CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED

What is fun about this error, is the kernal is trash and I have to start over..   "it must be destroyed"  love it!!!!

CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED An exception occurred on the device while executing a kernel. Common
causes include dereferencing an invalid device pointer and accessing out of bounds shared memory. The
context cannot be used, **so it must be destroyed** (and a new one should be created). All existing device
memory allocations from this context are invalid and must be reconstructed if the program is to continue
using CUDA.

OK, so now you know my background.  Here are my questions.
1.  How do I now how much is too much ( off line )?   Is there some type of python math or library that is good at knowing where I am memory wise while I am interactive?

2. Can I check for this situation "on line"?    So either before I call the vectorized fucntion, can I estimate live, if I am going to blow up memory and trash my kernal?    Or can I do it in the Vectorized procedure and have more control or insight to the memory allocation?
3. Will a Try / Exception block save me?   Or is the memory allocation too deep in the CUDA that once it blows up, it is gone, and the pythong wrapper cannot save the kernal..  "It MUST BE DESTROYED"...

Thanks, as you can see, just trying to push how many calculations I can run through on these GPUs..

Comment: The error has nothing to do with memory. It has to do with how long your code takes to run

Comment: I get the same problem when I run a similar function.  But the result is different.   Instead of getting the CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED  I get a CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY   ...  Let me post that code.   Because for that instance, I can see that the GPU memory is spiking up..

Comment: also, I tried the fix of editing the registry for windows 10 and it had zero impact.   Not sure this is really answered.